# Deploying AWS API Gateway lambda - BadRequestException: Invalid model identifier specified: Empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

Newcomer to the AWS computing using terraform

I have two files for declaring an AWS API Gateway and it fails when trying to deploy using gitlab ci, especially when it is treating the generated module

```bash
 Error: Error creating API Gateway Method Response: BadRequestException: Invalid model identifier specified: Empty
│ 
│   with module.corslambdaApiHelloWorld.aws_api_gateway_method_response._,
│   on .terraform/modules/corslambdaApiHelloWorld/main.tf line 63, in resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "_":
│   63: resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "_" {
```

Here is the file that generates that module:

```
// https://domain/{base}/helloworld
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "ApiResourceHelloWorld" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  parent_id     = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.root_resource_id
  path_part     = "helloworld"
}

module "corslambdaApiHelloWorld" {
  source            = "squidfunk/api-gateway-enable-cors/aws"
  version           = "0.3.3"

  api_id            = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  api_resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.ApiResourceHelloWorld.id

  allow_methods     = ["GET"]
}
```

And here is the resource generated in the module file when I use `terraform init` in my local workspace

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "_" {
  rest_api_id = var.api_id
  resource_id = var.api_resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method._.http_method
  status_code = 200

  response_parameters = local.method_response_parameters

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_method._,
  ]
}
```

We have already tried declaring a resource using [this method](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method_response), but from the deployment process, it still generates the `response_models` with the same value

We have verified similar projects by using `terraform init` into their terraform codes, and it generates something similar as the modules

But those projects are deployed properly, unlike ours

Notes:

- using `terraform plan` in my workspace does not generate any error
- the lambda function attached to the API was deployed succesfully and is available when browsing the AWS console
- in the gitlab job console, this output is present:

```bash
  # module.corslambdaApiHelloWorld.aws_api_gateway_method_response._ will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "_" {
      + http_method         = "OPTIONS"
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + resource_id         = "m3aimb"
      + response_models     = {
          + "application/json" = "Empty"
        }
      + response_parameters = {
          + "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
          + "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true
          + "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = true
          + "method.response.header.Access-Control-Max-Age"       = true
        }
      + rest_api_id         = "7ptzpas417"
      + status_code         = "200"
    }
```

I mainly want to know what is supposed to be generated in that module for the build to pass

Additional note asked from comments:

- The dockerfile used by gitlab-ci is using `terraform_1.0.0_linux_amd64` installed using `wget`
- Tried using `hashicorp/aws v3.75.0` locally, getting the same error on `terraform apply` command

Comment: It seems like there wasn't an update to the module in quite a while. Which Terraform version are you using?

Comment: according to the dockerfile, the deployment process is using terraform v1.0.0, obtained via wget

Comment: How about provider version?

Comment: provider version for what exactly? I have a versions.tf file with as `required_providers` hashicorp/archive, hashicorp/aws and hashicorp/random with `required_version = ">= 0.13"`

Comment: the console output for the deploy job states v4.22.0 for aws, v3.3.2 for random and v2.2.0 for archive

Comment: Well, I am not sure that the module can work with the newer version of the AWS provider. Try anything in the `3.x.x` range and see if that will work. Version 4 of the provider introduced breaking changes (not sure if any of it is related to API Gateway though).

Comment: I tried using `hashicorp/aws v3.75.0` locally and on `terraform apply` command, it gives me the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it by declaring an "empty model" resource in the `api.tf` file

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_model" "emptyModel" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  name = "Empty"
  description = "This is a default empty schema mode"
  content_type = "application/json"

  schema = "{\n  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n  \"title\": \"Empty Schema\",\n  \"type\": \"object\"\n}"
}
```